# Binding HPA to a custom made apiservice

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Is it possible to configure HPA to work with different api-service for custom-metrics server and not `v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io`?

As in my case, `v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io` already bound to some other metrics server and I don't want to touch it.

I want to create my own metrics server, bind it to my own api-service and use this api-service with HPA in my namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HPA to any custom metrics available in your node following [the guide from official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#create-horizontal-pod-autoscaler).

In order to get the APIs available for you, metrics-server exposes metrics via APIs below:

- `/nodes` - all node metrics; `type []NodeMetrics`
- `/nodes/{node}` - metrics for a specified node; `type NodeMetrics`
- `/namespaces/{namespace}/pods` - all pod metrics within namespace with support for all-namespaces; `type []PodMetrics`
- `/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{pod}` - metrics for a specified pod; `type PodMetrics`

Full command to list available APIs looks like:

`kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"`

In case you are working on GCP or other cloud, there is a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#custom-metric_1) for Deploying the Custom Metrics in GCP

---

### UPDATE

Answering to your comments:

HPA able to read metrics from:

- metrics.k8s.io (resource metrics)
- custom.metrics.k8s.io(custom metrics)
- external.metrics.k8s.io(external metrics)

> The common use for HorizontalPodAutoscaler is to configure it to fetch metrics from [aggregated APIs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/apiserver-aggregation/) (`metrics.k8s.io`, `custom.metrics.k8s.io`, or `external.metrics.k8s.io`). The `metrics.k8s.io` API is usually provided by an add on named Metrics Server, which needs to be launched separately. For more information about resource metrics, see [Metrics Server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/#metrics-server).

So, you can take anything from `metrics.k8s.io` that is available to your cluster. Or you can create your own APIService:

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: <name of the registration object>
spec:
  group: <API group name this extension apiserver hosts>
  version: <API version this extension apiserver hosts>
  groupPriorityMinimum: <priority this APIService for this group, see API documentation>
  versionPriority: <prioritizes ordering of this version within a group, see API documentation>
  service:
    namespace: <namespace of the extension apiserver service>
    name: <name of the extension apiserver service>
  caBundle: <pem encoded ca cert that signs the server cert used by the webhook>
```

Please find a [full guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-aggregation-layer/) on creating your APIService. Have fun :)

Comment: i think it's not what I need, i want HPA to work with  "/apis/my.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Comment: as custom.metrics.k8s.io already in use

Comment: @YerivanLazerev, updated my answer answering your comments

Comment: sorry for late reply, based on your answer I cant use my own api e.g. my.metrics.k8s.io

Comment: @YerivanLazerev, no, you can't. Consider one of the solution I've provided

Comment: custom.metrics.k8s.io - is already occupied